# VB.NET DataGridView - How to find out Column 1 value if you know row value from Column 2

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have a DataGridView which is set out in the following way:

```
OrderID - OrderPrice - CustomerName
   01   -   £9.99    -  John Stones
```

I currently have a ComboBox with all the Customer names (the ComboBox is binded with the DataGridView but only shows the CustomerName Column). When I select John Stones in the ComboBox I want a label indicating the OrderID of the selected item in the ComboBox. Therefore once I select John Stones in the ComboBox, label1.text should equal 01 - since that's the OrderID for the CustomerName John Stones.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Can you show us how you set up your binding? Is it from a dataset where you set the display member of the combobox? If so, you have a ValueMember property that can hold the OrderID in the item of the combobox. There are numerous ways of doing this and knowing how you coded what you have may be helpful in getting the other information you need without iterating through the dgv and matching strings.

Comment: after reading your comment below. It seems like you would probably be better off limiting your datagridview off of the combobox selection. So if you select John Stones in the combobox, the datagridview only shows John Stones orders. This can be done by creating a dataview and setting its rowfilter property off the combobox. Because as you pointed out, you may have multiple orders from John Stones but there is no way to select the actual order you intend unless John Stones appears multiple times in the combobox (each one associated with a particular row) and even which one do you select?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to loop through all of the DataGridView rows, see code example

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'String varible to store OrderID
    Dim OrderID As String = ""
    'Loop through all rows
    For g As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount
        'Check if a row contains ComboBox1.Text as value in cell 3
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Item(g).Cells.Item(2).Value = ComboBox1.Text Then
            'Set value of OrderID
            OrderID = DataGridView1.Rows.Item(g).Cells.Item(0).Value.ToString()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`DataGridView1.Rows.Item(g)` returns the row which has the index `g`, which increases by one every time the loop loops. `.Cells.Item(2).Value` returns the value of the cell in the third column of the datagridview. This is the same inside the `If`-function, where the value of the first cell in that row gets assigned to `OrderID`.

Comment: Thank's for your contribution. The problem with this code is that if there are 2 customers with the same name the wrong OrderID can be returned :/

Comment: You have this problem with any other solution as well. if two values are the same, the first hit gets returned. You should use a ID-based system where each customer has his own ID. BTW: I highly appreciate any upvotes